# Angular modal window depenging on server answer

Tags: angularjs, http, modal-dialog

Good day! I am rather new to angular and I need help in creating a directive or, maybe, some other solution. I have got a list of news, which are displayed one after another. It is done by ng-repeat. Inside each new there are a things like creationDate, post.media and etc. I would a new to appear in a modal window, when user clicks directly on the div with a new text. But, i would to make a request to the server after click to get the most recent version of the new.

So, this is what I want briefly:
1) User clicks on new's text.
2) The id is sent to the server.
3) Server responds with all post information
4) Some specified template loads with all information got from server and appears in a modal window.

What i tried to do:

I tried to create a directive and placed it on new's text. I created an isolated scope, which expects to have one more attribute, so I could get a postId.

```
scope: {
  postId: '@'
}
```

I created a template and specified a link to it as templateURL.

Then i created a link function and inside it i created smth like this :

```
     element.on('click', function() {
            scope.postInfo = scope.findPostById(postId);
        });
```

But for now, this directive just replaces its innerHTML :))

Some requirments:

Modal window should appear only after server receives all the information.

Thank you :)

Comment: i assume that new is singular to news which is wrong  news is both singular and plural

Answer (score 0):

Basically ng-repeat creates scope for every single element. So you just need to create a function i.e.

```
$scope.fetchNews = function(news){
   newsRepository.find(news).then(function(result){       
     $modal.open({
         templateUrl:...
         controller:...
         resolve:{
            news:function(){
              return result;
            }
         }
     })
   })
}
```

And in the controller of the model you inject as depenency news and after that you are done :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) It helped me to understand how it is done. But I was told, that taking information from cache will be okey :)